# Convert Response to key with values

Tags: java, spring

I have a JPA projection which returns this response:

```
[
    {
        "active": 0,
        "created_at": "2023-11-07T18:06:56",
        "blocked": 0
    },
    {
        "active": 13,
        "created_at": "2023-12-07T18:06:56",
        "blocked": 0
    }
]
```

from this Projection:

```
    List<CompaniesResult > result = .....;
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);

    public interface CompaniesResult {
    
        LocalDateTime getCreated_at();
    
        Integer getActive();
    
        Integer getBlocked();
    }
```

I want to return the result like this:

```
{
    "2023-11-07T18:06:56" : { "active": 0, "blocked": 0},
    "2024-11-07T18:06:56" : { "active": 20, "blocked": 10}
{
```

Do you know how I can convert this Java list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure of your exact requirements but I would probably return it in another way. But if this is how you want to return it you can use a nested map:

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>> companyResults() {
    List<CompaniesResult> result = ...; // 
    
    // Create a Map to store the converted data
    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> convertedData = new HashMap<>();
    
    for (CompaniesResult company : result) {
        LocalDateTime createdAt = company.getCreated_at();
        Integer active = company.getActive();
        Integer blocked = company.getBlocked();
        
        Map<String, Integer> innerJson = new HashMap<>();
        innerJson.put("active", active);
        innerJson.put("blocked", blocked);
        
        convertedData.put(createdAt.toString(), innerJson);
    }
    
    // Return the map as a JSON response
    return new ResponseEntity<>(convertedData, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```